# In which Maven phase actually user defined properties in pom.xml are initialised

Tags: maven

I have defined 1 property in pom.xml as follows -

```
    <properties>
        <val1>${value1}</val1>
    </properties>
```

Now when i use following cmd - mvn package -Dvalue1="This is value1"

Can anyone help to know in what phase, actually val1 property is initialised. During test phase, copy-resource phase, package etc etc ?

Comment: What you're looking for is [Model Interpolation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-model-builder/index.html), which happens before any lifecycle phase as far as i know. See the [full reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/) for all details.

Comment: Can you explain why you need such properties for what purpose... apart from that such property is interpolated during the load of the model (in other words of the pom file)...

Comment: Hello. I was thinking i will pass environment value(prod/qa/staging) in this parameter and then in my java class, using System.getProperty("val1"), i will use if else condition like if environment is qa, then base url will be set accordingly, if platform is prod, then base url will be set accordingly . So interoplation happpens before maven lifecycle, you mean ?

Comment: Maven properties are not automatically System properties (but there is a [plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html) to make them system properties). But also keep in mind that the maven properties are only available during maven lifecycle phases; once your `jar` is packaged they are gone (and need to be set again on application startup).